# How to write this equation in multi-line?

Tags: equations

I want this in multi-line equation

```
\[  
\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{split}
 a_{1,1}    &= d_{1},\\
 a_{k},k-1  &= \ell_{k-1}d_{k-1} \quad\quad   k=2:n\\
 a_{k,k}    &= d_{k} + \ell^2_{k-1}d_{k-1} 
             =d_{k}+\ell_{k-1}\alpha{k,k-1},   k=2:n
\end{split}        
\end{array}
\]
```

as shown in this page:

[image]

i want this output i try many solution please help

Comment: Don't take that blog as an example of good LaTeX coding. It isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using, for example, the enviroment `align*` instead of the enviroment `split`, you could to obtain the same output of your image.

**EDIT** after the comment of @barbarabeeton (see below) for the use of `\colon` instead of `:`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a_{1,1}& = d_{1},&\\
a_{k,k-1}&= \ell_{k-1}d_{k-1},& k=2\colon\! n, \\
a_{k,k}&=d_{k}+\ell^{2}_{k-1}d_{k-1}=d_{k}+\ell_{k-1}\alpha_{k,k-1},& k=2\colon \!n. 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

See the output:

[image]

Comment: Is question now more easy to understand? However, meanwhile you provide good answer! +1

Comment: @Zarko I don't want ahahha votes. I'm still laughing.

Comment: My votes are very serious!

Comment: `\colon` is what is in the OP's example; not `:`.  Also, `amssymb` isn't needed for this particular example; `\ell` is a "basic" symbol, part of the default symbol set.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have upvoted you before and I will do after the edit for your comment. I use \colon for the functions.

Comment: @Sebastiano -- Thank you, but no, I have deleted my answer.  It was the same as yours except for the two items mentioned in my comment.  You got there first.  (And I have apparently gotten caught while the TeX Live system on the "foreign" computer I'm using was in the midst of an update; I don't have TeX on my ancient laptop.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Let us give Caesar what is Caesar's.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Original output}

The following resembles the original, which has the big defect of unsightly
large space around the equals signs
\[
\begin{array}{lclll}
a_{1,1}   &=& d_{1}, \\
a_{k,k-1} &=& \ell_{k-1}d_{k-1},                                          && k=2{:}n, \\
a_{k,k}   &=& d_{k}+\ell^{2}_{k-1}d_{k-1}=d_{k}+\ell_{k-1}\alpha_{k,k-1}, && k=2{:}n.
\end{array}
\]

\section{Better}

This realization has the correct spacing around the equals signs and preserves
left alignment for the first column
\[
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&a_{1,1}   &&= d_{1}, \\
&a_{k,k-1} &&= \ell_{k-1}d_{k-1},                                          &\qquad& k=2{:}n, \\
&a_{k,k}   &&= d_{k}+\ell^{2}_{k-1}d_{k-1}=d_{k}+\ell_{k-1}\alpha_{k,k-1}, &\qquad& k=2{:}n. 
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `alignedat` one can precisely control the space between columns; there are three pairs of right aligned/left aligned columns; the first and third columns are actually empty, while the fifth only contains space.

Comment: Very very nice the `{:}`  which I have forgotten...